# What is the JavaScript engine that runs mongoDB shell?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

Is it V8? Can't seem to find this information.

Comment: It is v8 now http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/2.4/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As of [v3.1.7](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/127802855483/mongodb-317-is-released) it is SpiderMonkey - confirmed on the MongoDB 3.2 [release notes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.2/#spidermonkey-javascript-engine).

The reasons are explained on the [compatibility notes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.2-compatibility/#spidermonkey-compatibility):

> The change allows the use of more modern JavaScript language features, and comes along with minor mongo shell improvements and compatibility changes

There are some further notes on [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.2-javascript/).

A recent MongoDB release [v3.3.5](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/143704214273/mongodb-335-is-released) received an [update](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-23358) to the SpiderMonkey version to 45.0.2 ESR.

Development on switching back to SpiderMonkey from V8 was carried out in the v3.1.6 release - see [SERVER-18531](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-18531), but SpiderMonkey was not enabled by default until v3.1.7 - see [SERVER-19376](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-19376).

Before v3.1.6 it was the [V8](https://code.google.com/p/v8/) JavaScript engine, which became the default in v2.3.1, according to the [release notes](https://jira.mongodb.org/secure/ReleaseNote.jspa?projectId=10000&version=11883) and is also highlighted in the v2.4 [release notes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/2.4-javascript/).

SpiderMonkey was [removed from the source](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-9775) in v2.5.1

Before that, it was an extended [SpiderMonkey](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/SpiderMonkey) v1.7 shell that used some non-standard JavaScript extensions, for example the [ECMAScript for XML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/Web/E4X) extensions.

It seems to have been V8 even further back, but was migrated in [April 2009](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/101474817/migrating-to-spider-monkey) from V8 to SpiderMonkey. It looks like it was still SpiderMonkey for MongoDB in v1.1.4 according to [this post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-user/ahY-V3oJW-M), but I can't find out when the original switch was.

Comment: I wonder why they went from V8 to SpiderMonkey.

Comment: @AlexFord I suspect the original reason was V8 did not support all the extensions that mongoDB wanted to support. It's all V8 now.

Comment: [More details](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/2.4-javascript/)

Comment: ...and they're back to spidermonkey (https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-23358). Now I am really curious about the reasons for these switches. There are probably some big discussions somewhere in the Jira issue tracker.

Comment: Thanks @DanRoss, I'll be updating the answer now. Clearly I haven't been watching the MongoDB releases for a while

Comment: Can MongoDB execute any Javascript program?

Comment: It seems pretty unlikely MongoDB can execute _any_ JavaScript code, but you can certainly write [scripts for the shell](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/write-scripts-for-the-mongo-shell/) to execute. If you have a specific example, it might be best asked as a separate question.

Comment: why switch from V8 to SpiderMonkey? [detailed answer](https://engineering.mongodb.com/post/code-generating-away-the-boilerplate-in-our-migration-back-to-spidermonkey)

Answer (score 5):

MongoDB uses SpiderMonkey, not V8.

Source: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/mongo+-+The+Interactive+Shell

[You can build MongoDB with V8](http://nosql.mypopescu.com/post/409039261/using-googles-v8-javascript-engine-with-mongodb) if you want.