# How can I run a bare JavaScript file with Mongo Shell?

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb, mongo-shell

I know that MongoDB has a Nodejs driver, but also all the MongoDB commands are essentially  JavaScript code. Is there a way I can run a JavaScript file directly without depending on Nodejs driver? For example:
`mongo somejavascriptfile.js`, and have is interact with your databases as one wishes? Assume the `somejavascriptfile.js` has this kind of content.

```js
use companies;
show collections;

db.myCollection.insertOne({name: "New Company", location: "Nice Location"});
```

Comment: @Liam *The mongo shell is an interactive JavaScript interface to MongoDB* https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/mongo/

Comment: @Amani See similar posts: See [How to load multiple js files to database using mongo shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64001464/how-to-load-multiple-js-files-to-database-using-mongo-shell/64003009#64003009) and [Make a script to create MongoDB collections from Mongo shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58758740/make-a-script-to-create-mongodb-collections-from-mongo-shell/58785977#58785977)

Comment: You state correctly "MongoDB commands are essentially JavaScript code" - so what is your question? Simply run the js file.

Comment: @Liam, that's wrong. The mongoshell has a build-in [JavaScript engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8331099/what-is-the-javascript-engine-that-runs-mongodb-shell). You don't need neither a browser nor Node.

Comment: Well that's kinda true. Your correct it doesn't use node. It uses [SpiderMonkey it seems](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-23358) which is the Mozilla engine packaged up in a similar fashion to Node. Mongo themselves don't actually write the engine though.

Answer (score 3):

Update

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/write-scripts-for-the-mongo-shell/#--eval-option

> Use the --eval option to mongo to pass the shell a JavaScript fragment, as in the following:

> mongo test --eval "printjson(db.getCollectionNames())"

**Option 1-**

```
// somejavascriptfile.js

db.myCollection.insertOne({name: "New Company1", location: "Nice Location"})
// run
mongo myDB somejavascriptfile.js
```

**Option 2-**

```
// somejavascriptfile.js
db.getSiblingDB('companies').myCollection.insertOne({name: "New Company", location: "Nice Location"});
db.getSiblingDB('companies1').myCollection.insertOne({name: "New Company", location: "Nice Location"});
db.getSiblingDB('companies3').myCollection.insertOne({name: "New Company", location: "Nice Location"})
// run
mongo somejavascriptfile.js
```

---

Yes, you can run the script `somejavascriptfile.js` like this

```
mongo myDB somejavascriptfile.js // on a specific databse

mongo somejavascriptfile.js
```

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongo/#std-option-mongo.--eval

> --eval 
> Evaluates a JavaScript expression that is specified as an argument. mongo does not load its own environment when evaluating code. As a result, many options of the shell environment are not available.

```
mongo myDB --eval "var myVar = 'testVar'" somejavascriptfile.js // pass some variables to your script
```

---

Also, read

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/load/

> Loads and runs a JavaScript file into the current shell environment.

> The load() method has the following parameter:

```
load("scripts/myjstest.js")
load("/data/db/scripts/myjstest.js")
```

Comment: @Liam what node ? In the mongo shell, you can run JS,

Comment: @Liam Please read here https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/write-scripts-for-the-mongo-shell/#:~:text=Execute%20a%20JavaScript%20file&text=js%20script%20in%20a%20mongo,using%20the%20Mongo()%20constructor.

Comment: @Liam https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/write-scripts-for-the-mongo-shell/#--eval-option

Comment: Well it actually uses [spidermonkey it seems](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-23358). Still Mongo doesn't actually process anything so I fail to see why the OP would want this.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from provided answer you can also run

```
echo 'db.myCollection.insertOne({name: "New Company1", location: "Nice Location"})' | mongo myDB

mongo myDB <<< 'db.myCollection.insertOne({name: "New Company1", location: "Nice Location"})' 

mongo myDB <<EOF
use companies;
show collections;
db.myCollection.insertOne({name: "New Company", location: "Nice Location"});
EOF
```